# Get the current page URL in mvc returns incorrect data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I set two domains for my host in IIS.
www.z1.com
www.z2.com

I enter my website `www.z1.com` in the browser .I want to get the entered URL in my browser.my MVC code as you can see :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

But it returns `www.z2.com`
why ?

Comment: You can use window.location browser api.

Comment: Look at the request headers in your browser.  What is the `host` header's value?

Comment: In the browser it is Www.z1.com

Comment: To be clear, that is the **host** header, not the url in the browsers main window?